# Output Element ID to Console

Tags: javascript

I'd like to output the ID of an element when clicked to the browser console, however I can't work out how to do so in string format - currently the output is blank.

The HTML:

```
<div id = "1" class = "column">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)"> <img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/By-Product.png" alt="By Product" /></a>
 </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function addClassToImage(element) 
  {
    var innerImage = element.querySelector('img');
    var id  = element.id;
    if(innerImage) 
    {
      if(innerImage.classList.contains('clicked')) 
      {
        innerImage.classList.remove('clicked');
      }
      else 
      {
        innerImage.classList.add('clicked');
        console.log(id);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"how to do so in text format"_ - What do you mean by that? The id of an element will always be a string

Comment: Apologies - I meant string format and also should have stated that currently the output in the browser console is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current code only the parent element has `id` attribute and you are trying to get the id of the clicked element instead of that get parent node and then its id. Where parent node reference can get using [`Node#parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property of the node.

```js
function addClassToImage(element) {
  var innerImage = element.querySelector('img');
  // get parent node and then its id
  var id = element.parentNode.id;
 
  if (innerImage) {
    if (innerImage.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      innerImage.classList.remove('clicked');
    } else {
      innerImage.classList.add('clicked');
      console.log(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="column">
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)"> f<img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/By-Product.png" alt="By Product" /></a>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case you want to get the id of the closest ancestor which have id attribute then use [`Node#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method along with CSS [has attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)(as *[@T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)* suggested).

```js
function addClassToImage(element) {
  var innerImage = element.querySelector('img');
  // get parent node and then its id
  var id = element.closest('[id]').id;
 
  if (innerImage) {
    if (innerImage.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      innerImage.classList.remove('clicked');
    } else {
      innerImage.classList.add('clicked');
      console.log(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="column">
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)"> f<img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/By-Product.png" alt="By Product" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or if you want to allow for further nesting, `var id = element.closest("[id]").id;`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : yes that's right... I'd only heard about jQuery `closest()` now JS also implemented :) thanks....

Comment: Not JavaScript, the DOM. JavaScript is the language. The DOM is the API to the browser's UI.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : sorry my mistake, thanks for the correction as well :)

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks for the advice and also the lesson :)